# Xcode9 made my Iphone7 screen go black

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I launched an app with my own iphone7. the app had nothing on it. It is a single page application in IOS. when I ran the app it made my phone's screen go black. I can still get messages and it makes sounds, but the screen is black so I can not use it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Comment: Yea i tried to do the hard reset, but it does not work

Comment: Did the hard reset not work or did restarting the phone not solve the problem?

Comment: You did stop your app, right? Can you still back it up in iTunes? Run it in recovery mode in iTunes?
Restore from iTunes backup? Or set up as new phone in iTunes (losing all apps & data)? If none of those fix it, could just be a coincidence & you fried hardware somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're still running the app itself, and because your app has no content, it shows a black screen by default. If that's the case, you can forcibly terminate the app by double-tapping on the `Home` button, and then swiping down on the problematic app.

As an alternative, you could try soft resetting the device itself, by holding the `Sleep` button and the `Home` button at the same time for 10 seconds.

As a last resort, you can hard reset the device under `Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset` -> `Erase All Content And Settings`. Note that this will erase *everything* on the device, so should only be attempted if nothing else works.

Comment: hard reseting iPhone 7 is different, you have to use the 'volume down button + lock button'. See [these steps](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/09/how-hard-reset-iphone-7.html)